# Changing the date format of the file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have file like this called Sample.txt:

```
[Sat Sep 10 06:31:41 2016]!Node2!Node1!Node3
[Sun Sep 11 23:31:41 2016]!Node2!Node1!Node3
```

I need to modify it so it looks like.I need to change the date format to this format

```
  2016-09-10 06:31:41!ER_DEV!Node2!Node1!Node3
  2016-09-11 23:31:41!ER_DEV!Node2!Node1!Node3
```

Comment: i am trying to use awk command .to rearrange as per the format butb unable to get how to change the month into number . awk -F'!' '{print $1}'  Sample.txt | awk '{print $5 "-" }'

Comment: @StephenHarris Not exactly the same to the marked one, this one requires a conversion of date format, although other logics are similar.

Comment: @StephenHarris :Thanks for the reply. I need to tweak the date.. so thats where i was struck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` with help from `date`:

```
awk -F '[[\\]]' '{cmd="date -d \""$2"\" \"+%F %T\""; cmd | getline out; print out $3}'
```

- `-F '[[\\]]'` sets the field delimiter as either `[` or `]`, so the date would be in field 2 and the rest in field 3
- Variable `cmd` contains the `date` command for converting second field to desired form, `getline` runs the external `date` command and the output is saved in variable `out`
- Finally the content of variable `out`, and the 3rd field are printed

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
[Sat Sep 10 06:31:41 2016]!Node2!Node1!Node3
[Sun Sep 11 23:31:41 2016]!Node2!Node1!Node3

% awk -F '[[\\]]' '{cmd="date -d \""$2"\" \"+%F %T\""; cmd | getline out; print out $3}' file.txt
2016-09-10 06:31:41!Node2!Node1!Node3
2016-09-11 23:31:41!Node2!Node1!Node3
```

Comment: Thanks heemayl.Appreciate your help.I am not good in unix.. i am trying  very lenghty and  tough way..  Thats y i want to know if there is any way other easy to do. Sorry and Thank u

Comment: @Naresh No problem. Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `strptime`/`strftime` from the perl `Time::Piece` module:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -pe '
  s/\[(.*?)\]/Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")->strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S!ER_DEV")/e
' Sample.txt
2016-09-10 06:31:41!ER_DEV!Node2!Node1!Node3
2016-09-11 23:31:41!ER_DEV!Node2!Node1!Node3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this brute-force pure `sed` command:

```
sed 's/^.... //
     s/^Jan /01/; s/^Feb /02/; s/^Mar /03/; s/^Apr /04/; s/^May /05/; s/^Jun /06/
     s/^Jul /07/; s/^Aug /08/; s/^Sep /09/; s/^Oct /10/; s/^Nov /11/; s/^Dec /12/
     s/^\(..\) /\10/; s/^\(..\)\(..\)\( ........\) \(....\)./\4-\1-\2\3/'
```

- `s/^.... //` strips off the `[`
  and the (three-letter abbreviation of the) day of the week.
- `s/^Jan /01/` etc., replaces the
  (three-letter abbreviation of the name of the) month
  (and the following space)
  with the corresponding numeric value (month number).
- `s/^\(..\) /\10/` checks for a date (day-of-the-month) value
  that is one digit (i.e., a number < 10 with a leading space)
  and changes it to have a leading zero. 
  For example,

    `[Sat Sep  3`
    →
    `09 3`
    →
    `0903`
- `s/^\(..\)\(..\)\( ........\) \(....\)./\4-\1-\2\3/`
  converts the remaining date/time string
  from `mmdd HH:MM:SS YYYY]` to *`YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`*. 
  (If you want leading spaces in your output, as your question shows,
  add them to this command.)

Notes:

- This does no error-handling. 
  If the input is not what you say it will be, the output will be scrambled.
- This hard-codes the names of the months in English,
  and does not adapt to locale.